# watir-webdriver dependency in mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, rubymine

I have a mac and am using the IDE Ruby Mine. I've tried to install watir-webdriver via the terminal with the code `sudo gem install watir-webdriver`

Terminal returns: 
With the release of Watir 6.0, the watir-webdriver gem has changed its name
to watir. Update your dependencies to use "watir", "~> 6.0"

Successfully installed watir-webdriver-0.9.9
Parsing documentation for watir-webdriver-0.9.9
Done installing documentation for watir-webdriver after 1 seconds
1 gem installed

If it's an issue with updating my dependencies how do I do that, I cannot find any information online.

In my gems folder I don't see watir installed. I installed cucumber successfully, i see that folder in there but not watir.

My version of ruby is ruby 2.4.0p0

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you don't see "watir-webdriver" installed? The message suggests it did install "watir-webdriver" correctly. The message is just suggesting that you switch to "watir" instead since that is the newer version - ie do a `sudo gem install watir`

Comment: the message in terminal says it it did install watir-webdriver. I went ahead and  installed water as per your code and it says it successfully installed. But I do not see it in the folder ~/Libray/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/        

Cucumber and some other gems are in there but not watir

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Mac user. In [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1794502/1200545), they suggest that `sudo gem install` might install to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install watir-webdriver now, Simply install watir which includes watir-webdriver. Currently they have included waiting arragement for each element which is available to you If you install watir, this will not be available to you If you install watir-webdriver separately.

If you write

```
b.text_field.set 'Hi'
```

With the installation watir, the above statement will automatically converted to

```
b.text_field.when_present.set 'Hi'
```

With the installation of Watir-webdriver, the above statement remains the same.

Note: This recent watir is not a meta gem which chooses between watir-webdriver and watir-classic, this completely lies on watir-webdriver.